# MySQL Как вывести уникальные данные в подзапросе

Tags: mysql

Есть две таблицы:

`tags` с полями `name` и `thumb_url`

`images` c полями `keywords`(список нескольких тегов через запятую), `ctr`, `url`

Задача, одним запросом, обновить у всех тегов путь до картинки (`thumb_url`), найдя самую популярную (`ctr`) картинку с таким же тегом. Но проблема в том что у каждой `image` в поле `keywords` несколько тегов и соотвественно эти теги получат один и тот же `thumb_url`. А надо сделать уникальные.

Вот мой запрос, помогите как в подзапросе брать только уникальные данные, либо вообще неправильным путем я пошел.

```
UPDATE tags
SET thumb_url = (SELECT url FROM images WHERE keywords LIKE CONCAT ('%', tags.name , '%')
ORDER BY ctr DESC LIMIT 1)
```

Comment: Как выбрать нужный урл, если у двух картинок есть общий тэг и одинаковый ctr?

Comment: надо выбрать следующую картинку по ctr

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT t1.name, t2.ctr, t2.url
FROM tags t1, images t2
WHERE FIND_IN_SET(t1.name, t2.keywords)
```

Этот запрос выведет все URL для каждого тега с их популярностями. Скажем, он будет Q1.

```
SELECT name, ctr
FROM Q1
GROUP BY name
```

Этот запрос даст максимальную популярность для тега. Скажем, он будет Q2.

```
SELECT Q1.name, MIN(Q1.url) url
FROM Q1, Q2
WHERE Q1.name=Q2.name AND Q1.ctr=Q2.ctr
GROUP BY Q1.name
```

Этот запрос даст один (в данном случае минимальный лексикографически) из наиболее популярных URL для каждого тега. Скажем, он будет Q3.

И заключительный аккорд:

```
UPDATE tags, Q3
SET tags.thumb_url = Q3.url
WHERE tags.name = Q3.name
```

Если не лень, можно собирать всё в один запрос. Но я бы обошёлся вьюшками.

Answer (score 1):

Можно вот так в один запрос (про "следующую фотку" не понял):

```
update tags t
inner join (
  select *, @i := IF(@prev = name, @i + 1, 1) cnt, @prev := name
  from (
    select name, url
    from tags
    inner join images on keywords LIKE CONCAT('%', name , '%')
    order by name, ctr desc
  ) ordered
  inner join (select @prev := null) prev
  inner join (select @i := 1) i
) counter on counter.name = t.name and counter.cnt = 1
set thumb_url = counter.url;
```

Самый глубоко вложенный запрос выбирает все записи в нужном порядке, чтоб потом было что фильтровать.

Его в качестве данных использует запрос уровнем выше. Он добавляет счётчик, чтоб видеть границы групп (нумерует от 1 каждый уникальный набор одного тэга).

А ещё уровнем выше эти данные используются в обновлении. Остаётся только объединить их по имени тэга и взять в каждой группе первую запись (максимальный ctr).

UPD.: тестировал тут http://rextester.com/l/mysql вот таким запросом:

```
drop table if exists tags;

create table tags (
  name char(5),
  thumb_url char(5)
)
select 'tag-1' name, null thumb_url union
select 'tag-2',      null           union
select 'tag-3',      null           union
select 'tag-4',      null;

drop table if exists images;

create table images (
  keywords char(12),
  ctr tinyint,
  url char(5)
)
select 'tag-1, tag-2' keywords, 1 ctr, 'img-1' url union
select 'tag-1, tag-3',          2,     'img-2'     union
select 'tag-2, url-3',          1,     'img-3'     union
select 'tag-2, url-4',          2,     'img-4';

update tags t
inner join (
  select *, @i := IF(@prev = name, @i + 1, 1) cnt, @prev := name
  from (
    select name, url
    from tags
    inner join images on keywords LIKE CONCAT('%', name , '%')
    order by name, ctr desc
  ) ordered
  inner join (select @prev := null) prev
  inner join (select @i := 1) i
) counter on counter.name = t.name and counter.cnt = 1
set thumb_url = counter.url;

select * from tags;
```

Получил вроде верный результат:

```
    name   thumb_url
1   tag-1  img-2
2   tag-2  img-4
3   tag-3  img-2
4   tag-4  NULL
```

Comment: работает, правда на большой базе проблема... `2891387 rows in set (2 min 19.87 sec)`

Comment: @AntonIvanov не удивительно. чего только стоит поиск `LIKE CONCAT('%', name , '%')`. это полный перебор. странная идея хранить тэги через запятую в текстовом поле. почему не привести всё к нормальной форме и вынести тэги в таблицу многое-ко-многому?